# How to achieve gradient color for a shape?

Tags: graphics

```
Graphics[{Red, Rectangle[{0,0},{1,1}]}]}
```

This can create a red rectangle. Is this possible to replace this `Red` with a gradient color, for example, change the `Opacity` from 0 to 1 based on the x coordinate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### `RegionPlot` and `ColorFunction`

```
RegionPlot[True, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
 ColorFunction -> (Opacity[#, Red] &), Frame -> False, 
 BoundaryStyle -> None]
```

[image]

#### `VertexColors`

```
Graphics[{Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
 VertexColors -> {Opacity[0, Red], Opacity[1, Red], Opacity[1, Red], Opacity[0, Red]}]}]
```

[image]

#### `Raster`

```
Graphics@Raster[Table[{1, 0, 0, y}, {x, 0, 1, 1/100}, {y, 0, 1, 1/100}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Where the VertexColors will affect the smoothness of other shape? For example, Show[Graphics[{Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
    VertexColors -> {Opacity[0, Red], Opacity[1, Red], 
      Opacity[1, Red], Opacity[0, Red]}]}], 
 Graphics[Circle[{0.5, 0.5}, 0.2]]]     The circle looks bad. But If I just use Red instead of VertexColors, the circle looks smooth. Mine is Methematica 10.4.

Comment: @QiZhong, I get the same effect in version 9. Don't know how to fix it. You might want to post it as a new question perhaps?

Comment: Thanks all the same. I will post as a new question.

Answer (score 3):

Since V 12.2 there is `LinearGradientFilling`:

```
Graphics[{LinearGradientFilling[{White, Red}], Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}]}]
```

[image]